# Tomcat 4.1 cant able to start in eclipse but it can start through terminal

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I can able to run my tomcat 4.1 through terminal but i can't run inbuilt with eclipse. when i start tomcat it throws an error :

> 

```
Sep 16, 2014 12:05:06 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-4040
Starting service Tomcat-Standalone
Apache Tomcat/4.1.31
Install path.1:/home/likewise-open/GLOBAL/Workspace/V4.3/WEBROOT
Install path.2:/home/likewise-open/GLOBAL/Workspace/V4.3/WEBROOT
Install path.3:/home/likewise-open/GLOBAL/Workspace/V4.3/WEBROOT
Install path.4:/home/likewise-open/GLOBAL/Workspace/V4.3/WEBROOT
Echain Real path.5:/home/likewise-open/GLOBAL/Workspace/V4.3/WEBROOT
Sep 16, 2014 12:06:13 PM org.apache.commons.digester.Digester endElement
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:324)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils.invokeMethod(MethodUtils.java:252)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:256)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:276)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1058)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1567)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostDeployer.install(StandardHostDeployer.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.install(StandardHost.java:772)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:671)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:450)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:2143)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.execute(Catalina.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.process(Catalina.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:156)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
Sep 16, 2014 12:06:16 PM org.apache.commons.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw error
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

But the same tomcat run through in my terminal. 
Kindly suggest where i am going wrong.

P.S : i am working on ubuntu 10.10, eclipse Kepler with tomcat 4.1 version.

Comment: Tomcat 4.1? Seriously? Upgrade immediately.

Comment: yea but my product requires jdk1.4 so unfortunately tomcat 4.1 should be given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Jakarta Tomcat 4.x` released about in 2002 - 2003. I didn't use the old stuffs like these. In my opinion, you shoud:
* Download and install `Eclipse` old version, as old as better  ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#Releases ). 
* Try `Tomcat 4.x plugin for Eclipse IDE`: http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html
Stop standalone `Tomcat` instance before run `Tomcat` from `Eclipse`.